# Any way to force Firefox to recognize my microphone without restarting it?

Tags: linux, firefox, arch-linux, microphone, pulse-audio

Whenever I restart pulseaudio, Firefox stops detecting my microphone and will remain that way until I also restart it, which I normally hate doing because it interrupts my flow.

Is there a way to make Firefox recognize my microphone on-the-fly?

Answer (score 0):

- i'll give you some things to try or consider
- but i'm not guaranteeing that they'll work or suit you

  1) get a separate mic to use just with pulseaudio or to use just with firefox

  2) disable or exit pulseaudio while you use firefox

  3) on firefox, check whether or not your mic settings have problems here:
  about:preferences#privacy

  4) refresh firefox

  5) check whether or not you have an up to date operating system, drivers, and apps

  6) check whether or not you have any extraneous, conflicting audio devices

  7) check whether or not you have any required, yet disabled audio devices

  8) check whether or not your sound card is fully compatible with pulseaudio